# What is the most efficient way to put multiple colours on a window, especially in frame-by-frame format?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I am making a game with C and X11. I've been trying for quite a while to find a way to put different coloured pixels on a window, frame by frame. I've seen fully developed games get thousands of frames per second. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I have seen 2-coloured bitmaps with XImages, allocating 256 colours on a fade of black-white, and using XPutPixel with XImages (which I wasn't able to figure how to create an XImage properly that could later have pixels put on it).

I have made this for loop that creates a random image, but it is, obviously, pixel-by-pixel instead of frame-by-frame and takes 18 seconds to render one entire frame.

```
XColor pixel;
for (int x = 0; x < currentWindowWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < currentWindowHeight; y++) {
        pixel.red = rand() % 256 * 256; //Converting 16-bit colour to 8-bit colour
        pixel.green = rand() % 256 * 256;
        pixel.blue = rand() % 256 * 256;
        XAllocColor(display, XDefaultColormap(display, screenNumber), &pixel); //This probably takes the most time,
        XSetForeground(display, graphics, pixel.pixel); //as does this.
        XDrawPoint(display, window, graphics, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that the 1000 FPS game you compare to are really doing something similar. They probably use pre-calculated textures which are just cinningly designed and applied to generate the "seemingly-random" effect. On the other hand, I also believet that you do not really want to do this either. The result would be eye-hurting, wouldn't it? FPS games usually work with graphics engines, which make drawing polygons with sophisticated shading (mostly on the GPU), not pixels.

Comment: `rand() % 256 * 256` => `rand() & ~0xFFU`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After three or so more weeks of testing things off and on, I finally figured out how to do it, and it was rather simple. As I said in the OP, XAllocColor and XSetForground take quite a bit of time (relatively) to work. XDrawPoint also was slow, as it does more than just put a pixel at a point on an image.

First I tested how Xlib's colour format works (for the unsigned long int represented as pixel.pixel, which was what I needed XAllocColor for), and it appears to have 100% red set to 16711680, 100% green set to 65280, and 100% blue set to 255, which is obviously a pattern. I found the maximum to be a 50% of all colours, 4286019447, which is a solid grey.

Next, I made sure my XVisualInfo would be supported by my system with a test using XMatchVisualInfo([expected visual info values]). That ensures the depth I will use and the TrueColor class works.

Finally, I made an XImage copied from the root window's image for manipulation. I used XPutPixel for each pixel on the window and set it to a random value between 0 and 4286019448, creating the random image. I then used XPutImage to paste the image to the window.

Here's the final code:

```
if (!XMatchVisualInfo(display, screenNumber, 24, TrueColor, &visualInfo)) {
    exit(0);
}
frameImage = XGetImage(display, rootWindow, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
while (1) {
    for (unsigned short x = 0; x < currentWindowWidth; x += pixelSize) {
        for (unsigned short y = 0; y < currentWindowHeight; y += pixelSize) {
            XPutPixel(frameImage, x, y, rand() % 4286019447);
        }
    }
    XPutImage(display, window, graphics, frameImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, currentWindowWidth, currentWindowHeight);
}
```

This puts a random image on the screen, at a stable 140 frames per second on fullscreen. I don't necessarily know if this is the most efficient way, but it works way better than anything else I've tried. Let me know if there is any way to make it better.

Comment: `255 = 0x000000FF`, `65280 = 0x0000FF00`, `16711680 = 0x00FF0000`. This is the RGB format `0x00BBGGRR`. Your gray value `4286019447` is same as `0x‭FF777777‬`, it's close to dark gray. The hi byte `FF` is alpha, it is usually ignored.

Comment: I hadn’t found anything stating it was in AABBGGRR format, but I figured that when testing. Thanks for the hexadecimal conversion, I didn’t add that. It also works in BBGGRR format, so no need for the alpha value, 0xFFFFFF is white as well as 0xFFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

Thousands of frames per second is not possible. The monitor frequency is about 100 Hz, or 100 cycles per second, that's roughly the maximum frame rate. This is still very fast. Human eye wouldn't pick up faster frame rates.

The monitor response time is about 5ms, so any single point on the screen cannot be refreshed more than 200 times per second.

8-bit is 1 byte, so 8-bit image uses one byte per pixel, each pixel is from 0 to 256. The pixel doesn't have red, blue, green component. Instead each pixel points to an index in the color table. The color table holds 256 colors. There is a trick where you keep the pixels the same and change the color table, this makes the image fade in and out or do other weird things.

In a 24-bit image, each pixel has blue, red, green component. Each color is 1 byte, so each pixel is 3 bytes, or 24 bits.

```
uint8_t red = rand() % 256; 
uint8_t grn = rand() % 256;
uint8_t blu = rand() % 256;
```

A 16-bit image uses an odd format to store red, blue, green. 16 is not divisible by 3, often times 2 colors are assigned 5-bits, and the 3rd color gets 6-bits. Then you have to fit these colors on one `uint16_t` sized pixel. It's probably not worth it to explore this.

The slowness of your routine is because you are painting one pixel at a time. You should paint to a buffer instead, and render the buffer once per frame. You might consider using other frame works like SDL. Other games may use things like OpenGL which takes advantage of GPU optimization for matrix operation etc.

Comment: In most games, frame rate is determined by how many frames are rendered in an amount of time, not how many get sent to the monitor. Yes, the maximum frame rate you would actually see would be relative to the monitor's response time, but that's only when the frame gets sent to the monitor, not when it is rendered. With modern GPUs, frames can be rendered many more times than they are seen.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a GPU. GPUs have a highly parallel architecture optimized for graphics (hence the name). To access the GPU you will use an API like OpenGL or Vulkan or make use of a Game Engine.